# How to get ALL combinations of array elements in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

If I have an array:

```
%w(a b c d e)
=> ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

I can get **some** combinations with

```
irb(main):071:0> %w(a b c d e).combination(3).to_a
=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"], ["a", "b", "e"], ["a", "c", "d"], ["a", "c", "e"], ["a", "d", "e"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["b", "c", "e"], ["b", "d", "e"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
```

However that is not ALL the combinations, just the unique ones, e.g. `["e", "a", "b"]` is missing

When I similarly try with s smaller array I only get one result:

```
irb(main):059:0> %w(a b c).combination(3).to_a  
=> [["a", "b", "c"]]
```

How can I get all 6 combinations, i.e. for `['a', 'b', 'c']` I want to get

```
[['a','b','c'], ['a','c','b'], ['b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b'], ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Similarly for `[1,2,3,4]` if I want **all** the 3 digit combo I should get

```
irb(main):074:0> [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,2],[1,3,4],[1,4,2],[1,4,3],  [2,1,3],[2,1,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,1],[2,4,1],[2,4,2],  [3,1,2],[3,1,4],[3,2,3],[3,2,4],[3,4,2],[3,4,1]]
```

?

Comment: are you looking for `permutation` instead? `[1,2,3,4].permutation(3).to_a`

Comment: Yes, that is it @kiddorails

Comment: great. added as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) instead of `combination`.

In combinations, we do not care about the order of the elements, and only care about the presence of all the elements in the set.

```rb
[1,2,3,4].permutation(3).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input: str = "AAB"
Output: 8
Explanation: The possible sequences are "A", "B", "AA", "AB", "BA", "AAB", "ABA", "BAA".
```

Code :-

```
arr= str.chars
new_arr = []

for index in 1..arr.length do
  new_arr<< arr.permutation(index).to_a.uniq
end

puts new_arr.flatten(1).count
```